# Error handler naming

Tags: vba, vb6

Is there a best practice for naming the error handling section?  How about the resume label?  I use "ErrorHandler:" and "ProcExit:". Thanks.

Comment: I use "EH".  If a code maintainer wonders what EH means, "On error goto EH" explains it all.

Comment: I often used Hell - "On Error GoTo Hell" looks reasonable too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really - apart from making sure it's reasonable. If I'm using On Error Resume Next however I usually indent the code after it, e.g.:

```
On Error Reume Next
   ' Do something at might cause an error
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' Do something to recover from error
   End If
On Error Goto 0 'or Goto errorhandler to restore that.
```

This gives a clear visual clue that you've temporarily disabled the normal error handling for a short period.

For the error handler label, I've used various including the dull 'ErrorHandler' and the rather more prosaic label 'OopsSorryIveCockedItUpAgain'. Both are fairly meaningful though :-)

Comment: Hehehehe.  I've got the odd little bits of code, mostly in Select Case modules which the user should never, ever encounter, which state "Tell Tony he's a moron." and similar.

Comment: @Tony: Steve McConnell tells a story in Code Complete of a user report of the error message "You have a bad pointer, dogbreath". He says luckily that user had a sense of humour, but he resolved not to put jokes in error messages again. You have to realise the user might be trying to get work done against a tight deadline and might not see the funny side. Obviously doesn't apply to things like error labels that the user won't see.

Comment: On the original question - just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen `ErrorHandler:` most often.

Answer (score 1):

Just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I use tagError: but as others have said be consistant.   I would also think that this is the only tag I use in about 99% of my code so it's not really that important.

I do very much like using [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) to insert my standard error handling code into new functions and subroutines with the press of an icon.  For VBA and VB6 it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I think what matters most is that your consistent.  That will make your code more readable by others and even yourself.  Not to mention more maintainable etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as the label is clear it's fine. Personally I use ErrHnd:

Answer (score 0):

Only because I can't resist adding my own preference, I prefer to name my error handlers **err***ProcedureName*.

example:

```
Public Function RecordCount(ByVal AddendumFile As String) As Long
Dim fHndl As Integer
Dim nLineCount As Long
Dim strRec As String  'single line from file

On Error GoTo errRecordCount
```

Comment: That's a bit too much work for me altough MZTools would make that real easy.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, I researched common naming conventions in VB6 for labels generally (case, separators, etc) and error handlers specifically and settled on

```
Err_Handler
```

Sorry, I can give no citation for this: too many years have passed and my links are broken!

Answer (score 0):

The best naming convention is the consistent one.